# PHPExcel - 'Invalid cell coordinate o1'

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

Estoy generando un código que pueda leer tanto ficheros ".xls" (Excel5) como ".xlsx" (Excel2007) y es curioso, porque el proceso que he generado obtiene los datos del fichero ".xls" correctamente, pero sin embargo si intento leer los datos del mismo documento (mismos datos y estructura) pero en formato ".xlsx" (resultado de "Guardar como" el fichero ".xls" como ".xlsx") no funciona.

En este caso, aparece el mensaje:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PHPExcel_Exception' with message 'Invalid cell coordinate o1' in C:\xampp\htdocs\CTS\admin\PHPExcel\Classes\PHPExcel\Cell.php:594 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\CTS\admin\PHPExcel\Classes\PHPExcel\ReferenceHelper.php(881): PHPExcel_Cell::coordinateFromString('o1') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\CTS\admin\PHPExcel\Classes\PHPExcel\ReferenceHelper.php(788): PHPExcel_ReferenceHelper->updateSingleCellReference('o1', 'A1', 0, 1) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\CTS\admin\PHPExcel\Classes\PHPExcel\ReferenceHelper.php(734): PHPExcel_ReferenceHelper->updateCellReference('o1', 'A1', 0, 1) #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\CTS\admin\PHPExcel\Classes\PHPExcel\Reader\Excel2007.php(295): PHPExcel_ReferenceHelper->updateFormulaReferences('=IF(AND($K8="Ho...', 'A1', 0, 1) #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\CTS\admin\PHPExcel\Classes\PHPExcel\Reader\Excel2007.php(885): PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007->castToFormula(Object(SimpleXMLElement), 'W9', 'f', '=', '0', Array, 'castToString') #5 C:\xampp\htdocs\CTS\admin\LeerFicheroExcel2.php(21): PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007-> in C:\xampp\htdocs\CTS\admin\PHPExcel\Classes\PHPExcel\Cell.php on line 594

Y no entiendo nada, porque si miro el fichero y busco por "o1" no encuentro ninguna celda. Las columnas van desde la A hasta la AC. Y las filas desde la 1 hasta la 184.

He hecho un seguimiento al código:

```
$archivo = $_FILES['fichero_usuario']['tmp_name'];
$inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($archivo);
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($archivo);
```

Y veo que el error me da en la línea del load:

```
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($archivo);
```

No entiendo si ambos ficheros tienen la misma estructura y contenido, porque con ".xls" funciona y con ".xlsx" no.

El tipo de fichero que almacena en "inputFileType" es correcto (Excel5 para ".xls") y (Excel2007 para ".xlsx").

Por favor, ¿podéis ayudarme con este tema?, ¿sabéis qué puede estar provocando el error?

Comment: ¿Puedes compartir el excel? Parece que el error lo genera la fórmula `=IF(AND($K8="Ho...', 'A1', 0, 1)` que trata de buscar `o1` (o minúscula). ¿Estás guardando seleccionando el formato adecuado o sólo cambiando la extensión? ¿Has probado a cambiar la expresión de tipo A1 a R1C1?

Comment: Hola Oscar, gracias por tu respuesta. No puedo enviarte el fichero porque contiene datos confidenciales y como lo publique por aquí se me cae el pelo. Lo que sí puedo confirmarte es que al guardarlo como .xlsx lo hago seleccionando el formato. Confirmado que es la fórmula porque si copio el contenido de la hoja afectada y lo pego como valor en la misma hoja, el proceso funciona correctamente.